# Emailing multiple potential Ph.D advisors, post admission and visitation

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor, engineering

I have recently been admitted into a Ph.D. program for Engineering, and have already visited the campus and met with potential advisors.

After my meetings, I have decided that I would be interested in working with several of the professors I met with, and I am unsure of how to go about reaching back out to multiple professors at the same school to learn about potential work in their respective labs.

Is it frowned upon to email various professors at the same department and school, and if not, is there a good way to go about asking them for a bit more information (than I had received in the initial meeting) about exactly what projects they have funding for?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, it's not frowned upon.